# mgcv: Use of s() or te() with interactions in GAMs?

Tags: interaction, generalized-additive-model, splines, mgcv, tensor

I am trying to model CO2 fluxes (fco2) using a number of environmental parameters using a GAM in mgcv.

Specifically, I have leaf temperature (tl), vapour pressure deficit (vpd), and soil water content (swc). vpd is a function of tl, air pressure and relative humidity (both not measured). I getting the best model response when I have a 3-way interaction between them, but also a relatively good one with an interaction between tl and vpd. Now I'm wondering about the following:

1. I am getting a lower AIC using `s()`, rather than `te()` in `m1` or `m2` below. Which one is correct and why is this?

```
m1 <- gam(fco2 ~ s(tl) + s(vpd) + s(swc) + ti(tl, vpd), data=df, method='REML')
m2 <- gam(fco2 ~ te(tl) + te(vpd) + te(swc) + ti(tl, vpd), data=df, method='REML')
```

2. Since vpd is a function of tl (among other things), should one of the two variables be removed? This significantly increases AIC though and lowers R<sup>2</sup>.

Thanks a lot for the help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The difference isn't really because you use `s()` or `te()`, but more because those two function generate smooth with different default bases. `s()` generates a low-rank thin plate spline basis, whereas `te()` uses a cubic regression spline basis for the marginal smooths.

   The correct way to express this model is using the `s(x, bs = "cr") + s(z, bs = "cr") + ti(x,z)` form. Although Simon allow's the `ti()` form (`ti(x) + ti(z) + ti(x,z)`) I find it a bit odd to create a tensor product interaction of a single variable. I know it works and gives effectively the same model as the `s()` form but I find the `ti()` version weird. The main plus in favour of the `ti()` form is that you are sure to get the right bases; with `s()` you need to specify the `cr` basis for example if you want to match the `ti()`, so it is something else that you need to think about and get right.
2. If `vpd` is a function of `tl`, then it is likely that your model suffers from a problem called concurvity, which is where a term in the model can be represented by smooth combination of the other terms in the model. You can check this with the `concurvity()` function in {mgcv}. You don't have to remove `tl`; it sounds like it is not just a simple function of `vpd` so you might be OK leaving it in and accepting any high concvurvity (if present).

Comment: Great answer, thanks so much!